# Understanding macro expansion

Tags: c, macros

I recently saw some code like this:

```
#define JOIN(lhs, rhs)   JOIN_(lhs, rhs)
#define JOIN_(lhs, rhs)  JOIN__(lhs, rhs)
#define JOIN__(lhs, rhs) lhs##rhs
```

I tested the code, calling like these:

```
JOIN(Foo, 0);
JOIN_(Foo, 1);
JOIN__(Foo, 2);

JOIN(Foo, JOIN(A,B));
JOIN_(Foo, JOIN(A,B));
JOIN__(Foo, JOIN(A,B));
```

The macros expand into the following symbols:

```
Foo0
Foo1
Foo2
FooAB
FooAB
FooJOIN
```

I get the purpose, it's resolving arguments differently. Calling any of the variations of `JOIN` is clearly not the same on the last case. But how are these macros being expanded? Why do the arguments behave differently?

Edit: [Here's](https://github.com/gpakosz/Assert/blob/master/src/pempek_assert.h) the file

Comment: I think, last macro `JOIN__(Foo, JOIN(A,B));' should be expanded as `FooJOIN(A,B)` and not just `FooJOIN`, please clarify.

Comment: It's possible. I get `warning: implicit declaration of function 'FooJOIN' is invalid in C99`, so I don't really see which arguments it's getting. But what you are saying makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

> 3.9.6 Argument Prescan
>
> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are
>   substituted into a macro body, unless they are stringified or pasted
>   with other tokens. After substitution, the entire macro body,
>   including the substituted arguments, is scanned again for macros to be
>   expanded. The result is that the arguments are scanned twice to expand
>   macro calls in them.
>
> Macros that call other macros that stringify or concatenate. If an
>   argument is stringified or concatenated, the prescan does not occur.
>   If you want to expand a macro, then stringify or concatenate its
>   expansion, you can do that by causing one macro to call another macro
>   that does the stringification or concatenation.

For instance, if you have

```
#define AFTERX(x) X_ ## x
#define XAFTERX(x) AFTERX(x)
#define TABLESIZE 1024
#define BUFSIZE TABLESIZE
```

then AFTERX(BUFSIZE) expands to X_BUFSIZE, and XAFTERX(BUFSIZE) expands to X_1024. (Not to X_TABLESIZE. Prescan always does a complete expansion.)

**CASE1**

`#define JOIN__(lhs, rhs) lhs##rhs` => since it has a token pasting operator, it will concatenate the macro arguments those are not completely macro-expansion before substituted. --> which is a bad way to expand and on first place we don't know, what will be the arguments it will be passed to it, it won't wait for its expansion and it will simply concatenate it.

hence, when ever you call `JOIN__(Foo, JOIN(A,B));`, it won't allow `JOIN(A,B)` to expand and it will concatenate it to FOOJOIN(A,B).

**CASE2**
now, on the other hand, 
`#define JOIN_(lhs, rhs)  JOIN__(lhs, rhs)` => here, there is no token pasting operator, Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body. hence, it will allow lhs and rhs to expanded and is called with expanded parameters  `JOIN__(FOO,AB)`, hence now, JOIN__ has a token pasting operator, it will simply concatenate it arguments FOO and AB i.e. FOOAB. which is the appropriate way to do it.

**CASE3**
`#define JOIN(lhs, rhs)   JOIN_(lhs, rhs)` => same as CASE2.

Hope, it explains the reason behind **multi-level expansion paradigm**.

**ORIGINAL**
 The preprocessor operator ## provides a way to concatenate actual arguments during macro expansion. If a parameter in the replacement text is adjacent to a ##, the parameter is replaced by the actual argument, the  ## and surrounding white space are removed, and the result is re-scanned. For example, the macro paste concatenates its two arguments:

```
#define  paste(front, back)  front ## back

so paste(name, 1) creates the token  name1.
```

Comment: I know about the token pasting operator. I'm asking about this multi-level expansion paradigm, not concatenation

Comment: @AndréFratelli: Please find the updated answer for `multi-level expansion paradigm`. Hope it explains what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome answer, really thorough.

Answer (score 1):

The `##` tokenize operator doesn't evaluate (macro-expand) its arguments. Function-like macro expansions **do** evaluate arguments, however, and that is why you get expected (evaluated) output for the first cases.

Technically, the macro `JOIN_` is unnecessary, since `lhs` and `rhs` in `JOIN` are evaluated when expanding `JOIN__`. This would suffice:

```
#define JOIN(lhs, rhs)   JOIN__(lhs, rhs)
#define JOIN__(lhs, rhs) lhs##rhs
```

Comment: I honestly can't find a situation in which you are wrong, but why would the code have been written like that?

Comment: Please see my edit. I included the original code

Comment: @AndréFratelli - Who knows? People do strange things... But I don't see any reason for the code to have been written that way.

Comment: I guess... I'll give it some more time before accepting, maybe we are missing something...